# What's the difference between Class Library and .NET Core Class Library templates?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm creating a new ASP.NET Core 1.0 application targeting the full .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Because I'll be running this app on Azure, I don't want to target the new .NET Core framework. I don't need to worry about running it on other platforms.

I now need to add a couple of class library projects to my solution to handle some back end functions. Which class library should I choose?

[image]

P.S. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Update 3 and as I mentioned, this will be an ASP.NET Core 1.0 app targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 that will run as a WebApp on Azure.

Comment: Go with Class Library (2nd option), comes with less stuff easier to manage if you don't need everything. Seems for your purpose it should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will only be ever targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 on Windows, just go with the normal Class Library template.

If you want to future-proof your code, use the Class Library (.NET Core) template and target `netstandard1.3` or higher in your library.